# Angular resource with response type text/plain always makes an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource

I made resource that receive records count from rest service as text plain. Angular makes an array of each chars from answer. For example if rest answers `20`, angular will make array `[2,0]`. Can I fix it without transforming response or using `$http`?

```
var resource = angular.module('resource');
resource.factory('RecordResource', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/rest/records/:id', {}, {
            count: {
                method:'GET',
                url: "/rest/records/count",
                isArray: false,
                responseType: 'text'
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: So how are you calling the count method on the resource?

Comment: I don't see anything in the [`defaultHttpResponseTransform`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L129) that would turn your string into an array. You'll need to show your code where you call the resource method and handle the response

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular has difficulty retrieving a list of strings with `$resource`. Some options you have include (suggestion two being what you likely want due to constraints in your question)...

1. Opting to leverage the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service instead
2. Return your response in a wrapped object such as `{ 'collection': [20, 40, 60] }`
3. Transform the response and access through a defined property e.g. `data.collection`. An example for transforming your response could include...

```
return $resource('/rest/records/:id', {}, {
    count: { 
        method:'GET',
        transformResponse: function (data) {
            return { collection: angular.fromJson(data) }
        [...]
```